# preg_match_all is not giving desired result

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a HTML content like this one

```
some html text [link id="1"]  some html text 
some html text [link id="2"]  some html text 
some html text [link id="3" stat="y"]  some html text 
some html text [link id="4" stat="y"]  some html text
```

I'm using

`var_dump(preg_match_all('/\[link([^\[]+)\]/',$html_tags, $result));`

to extract `[link]` tags from it and it is giving me an `array` like this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(4) {
    [0]=> string(13) "[link id="1"]"
    [1]=> string(13) "[link id="2"]"
    [2]=> string(21) "[link id="3" stat="y"]"
    [3]=> string(21) "[link id="4" stat="y"]"
  }
  [1]=> array(4) {
    [0]=> string(7) " id="1""
    [1]=> string(7) " id="2""
    [2]=> string(15) " id="3" stat="y""
    [3]=> string(15) " id="4" stat="y""
  }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can get the result like this

```
array (1){
    [0]=> array (4) {
        [0] => array (2){
            [id]  => string(1) "1"
            [stat] => string(0) ""
        }
        [1] => array (2){
            [id]  => string(1) "2"
            [stat] => string(0) ""
        }
        [2] => array (2){
            [id]  => string(1) "3"
            [stat] => string(1) "y"
        }   
        [3] => array (2){
            [id]  => string(1) "4"
            [stat] => string(1) "y"
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_meta_tags($html_tags)` does the exact result I want but how can I use it to get `[link]` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom written function and array_map.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
//first flatten array
$array = $array[1];
array_map("passone", $array);
array_map("passtwo", $array);


function passone ($n) {
    return substr($n, 1);
}

function passtwo ($n) {
    $nx = explode(" ", $n);
    preg_match("link=\"(.*?)\"", $nx[0], $matches);
    $ret['id'] = $matches[0];
    if (!empty($nx[1]))
    {
        $times = preg_match("stat=\"(.*?)\"", $nx[1], $matches);
        if ($times != 0)
        {
        $ret['stat'] = $matches[0];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: You are just awesome... thank you very much for this complete script.. thanks a lot :)

Comment: the second function has some error and always give me an array with false value, can you please fix it `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["stat"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["stat"]=>
    string(9) " sub="aa""
  }
}`